# change string in php after getting it from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have following data:

```
$var = $_POST['name'];
then $var="jay's Box"
```

change to:

```
$var = "jay\'s box"
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `addslashes()` function

```
$var = addslashes($var);
```

More information at http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php.

**Just a note**, the opposite of this function is `stripslashes()`.

Hope this helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at addslashes()

```
<?php
$quote = "Jay's Box";
print_r(addslashes($quote));
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php